# DBeaver: Redirect server output to file

Tags: dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver to execute a large script file which produces a lot of output (via PostgreSQLs RAISE NOTICE statement). I can see the output in the server output tab, however, the buffer size seems to be limited so a lot of output is lost at the end of the execution.

Is it somehow possible to either increase the server output tab buffer size or redirect the server output directly to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue as you, and I have been unable to find any setting which limits the output length.

In my case, what I eventually discovered was that there was an error in my script which was causing it to fail silently. It looks like part of the output is missing, however it was just the script terminating prematurely.

I encourage you to consider this option, and check your script for errors. Be aware that errors in the script don't appear in the output log.